# Create multiple bodies in Rest api Request

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I am new to SoapUI. I have an Rest api in which i need to create multiple bodies dynamically using groovy script in soapui. Currently it has two bodies. I have to create 200 "Bodies" with random "STID" on each body.how can i do that in soap ui.

```
{
  "Header": {
    "Hash": "casbucl"
  },
  "Body": [
    {
      "RequestInitiator": "XXXXX",
      "TCode": "01",
      "Date": "1018",
      "Time": "143254",
      "STID": "456857",
      "TransmissionDateTime": "1018121541"

    },
    {
      "RequestInitiator": "XXXX",
      "TCode": "01",
      "Date": "1018",
      "Time": "143254",
      "STID": "456876",
      "TransmissionDateTime": "1018121541"

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: For random `STID` you can use `UUID.randomUUID()`. And it seems you don't need to send "multiple bodies" (BTW - what does it mean?) , but rather one body with multiple objects.

Comment: Hi, what you're describing is a "data-driven test".  SoapUI Pro provides out of the box functionality for this.  If you're using the free version, then you need to use Groovy script to achieve the same effect.  There are several answer on SO that describe how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have done this by using groovy script.